# React Redux - Display string stored in Redux state within Input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an `input` field that the user types into. This Input field looks like this:

```
// within React component render function:
...
        <input
          id="autoComplete"
          className={inputClasses}
          type="text"
          // used to display user typed words in input field
          ref={this.inputRef}
          // onchange is used to store value in redux store
          onChange={this.inputChangeHandler}
        />
```

In the above code, the 'ref' is for displaying the user typed letter in the input field. However, I also have Google Maps Autocomplete integrated into this input field. The Autocomplete feature works fine & when the user clicks on one of the autocomplete results, the input field is populated by that name & `onChange` handler stores the value within the redux store.

So far, so good. However, now, when the user navigates to another section of the site, how do I populate the input field with the value within the redux store. There is no 'value' attribute on the input field, & its using React's `ref` method.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change/add value to input element using ref. `ref` will basically have the reference of actual dom node, so by changing `this.refName.current.value` will change the `input` value.

But you need to do it after initial rending, means after ref get the reference of input element.

Check this working example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.a = React.createRef();
  }
  
  click = () => {
    this.a.current.value = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref={this.a} placeholder="Number" />
        <button onClick={this.click}>Click here to change the input value</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Comment: Thank you Mayank, this was great help. I ended up using callback ref as it gives a bit more finer control. Thank you for the guidance.